# Change the currency symbol or remove it in the inputmask currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I'm using [Robin Herbot's inputmask jquery plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) and I want to change the default currency symbol (by default, its a dollar currency symbol) to a PESO currency symbol or remove the currency symbol.

Below is what I've tried, yes the symbol changes and the symbol is removed but it won't let me type anything.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#currency1").inputmask({ alias : "currency", mask : "0.00" });
  $("#currency2").inputmask({ alias : "currency", mask : "₱ 0.00" });

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.2.6/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<label>REMOVE CURRENCY SYMBOL</label><br>
<input type="text" id="currency1" /><br>
<label>CHANGE THE CURRENCY SYMBOL</label><br>
<input type="text" id="currency2" />
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can change the symbol by using the `prefix` option. Below is a snippet where I do this in two different ways, modifying the currency alias and defining my own alias.

In your version you couldn't type anything since the `mask` property is used to restrict input and setting it to `0.00` only allows those four characters to be entered and nothing else. A mask of `9.99` would allow a number followed by a period and two numbers. `9` has a special masking definition allowing any number.

```js
Inputmask.extendAliases({
  pesos: {
            prefix: "₱ ",
            groupSeparator: ".",
            alias: "numeric",
            placeholder: "0",
            autoGroup: true,
            digits: 2,
            digitsOptional: false,
            clearMaskOnLostFocus: false
        }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#currency1").inputmask({ alias : "currency", prefix: '' });
  $("#currency2").inputmask({ alias : "currency", prefix: '₱ ' });
  $("#currency3").inputmask({ alias : "pesos" });

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.2.6/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<label>REMOVE CURRENCY SYMBOL</label><br>
<input type="text" id="currency1" /><br>

<label>CHANGE THE CURRENCY SYMBOL</label><br>
<input type="text" id="currency2" /><br>

<label>CHANGE THE CURRENCY SYMBOL, using an alias</label><br>
<input type="text" id="currency3" />
```

Comment: Why do you use the `!0` and `!1` syntax? Is `false` and `true` too common? I find it unnecessary irritating.

Comment: @PeterVARGA I have absolutely no idea. Maybe I copy-pasted the code from somewhere and didn't notice that. Who knows, I barely remember what I did yesterday, much less five years ago. Edit: I did some googling and looks like that awful syntax has been used in some other inputmask examples as well, so copy-paste is my guess.

Comment: Thank you, no offence my friend. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Solution with data-inputmask attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").inputmask();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.2.6/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<label>REMOVE CURRENCY SYMBOL</label><br>
<input type="text" id="currency1" data-inputmask="'alias': 'decimal', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoGroup': true, 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': false, 'placeholder': '0'" style="text-align: right;"><br>
<label>CHANGE THE CURRENCY SYMBOL</label><br>
<input type="text" id="currency2" data-inputmask="'alias': 'decimal', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoGroup': true, 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': false, 'prefix': '₱ ', 'placeholder': '0'" style="text-align: right;">
```