# How to change data-inputmask prefix using dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I use [Robin Herbot inputmask plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) for currency inputs. I want to change the currency symbol each time when the exchange dropdown change event triggers. But the inputmask prefix prevents to change the currency symbol. I have this code:

HTML:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.exchange, 
               new SelectList(@ViewBag.rates, "Value", "Text",4), null, new
                       {
                           @Style = "height:34px;width:370px !important;font-size: 14px;",
                           @class = "form-control input-lg"
                       }
              )
 <input type="text"
                       class="form-control text-left monerate"
                       id="price1"
                       name="price1"
                       placeholder="₺ 0.00"
                       data-inputmask="'alias': 'numeric', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoGroup': true, 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': false, 'prefix': '₺ ', 'placeholder': '0'" />
```

JQuery:

```
  $('input.monerate').inputmask();

  $(document.body).delegate('#exchange', 'change', function () {  
        exchangeID = $('#exchange :selected').val();
        if (exchangeID == 1) {
            $("#price1").inputmask({ alias: "currency", prefix: '$ ' });           
        }
        else if (exchangeID == 2) {           
            $("#price1").inputmask({ alias: "currency", prefix: '€ ' });
        }
        else if (exchangeID == 3) {            
            $("#price1").inputmask({ alias: "currency", prefix: '£ ' });
        }
        else if (exchangeID == 4) {
            $("#price1").inputmask({ alias: "currency", prefix: '₺ ' });
        }        
    });
```

Are there a way to change the prefix?

I've read this answer but did not work for me:

> [Change the currency symbol or remove it in the inputmask currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008984/change-the-currency-symbol-or-remove-it-in-the-inputmask-currency)

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6kzjLd7u/10/

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of this code

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I added a fiddle

Comment: Unfortunately it!s not working @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Can you show me the code where its is NOT working ? Are you sure you are using my code i provided in the answer ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I can get the exchangeID already, but the problem is, it is not changing the placeholder "₺" nor prefix in the input box..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221736/discussion-between-always-helping-and-zeynep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your `on-change` function like this below. Also, the `value` of a select by default is `string` but you are checking the `value` as `integer` which is one reason your code did not work.

Add treat the option as integar we can use [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) (+) - adding a plus sign before getting the value will make it integar

```
var exchangeID = +$(this).val(); //parse as number - by default it is string
```

Secondly, for *Robin Herbot* `inputMask` to load dynamically and change `currency` prefix from the `dropdown` you need to assign the `initial` prefix in `jQuery` as well. Since you have defined in *statically* in the `HTML` it will **not** work as intended.

Lastly, your code is all fixed and working as intended with currency `prefix` changing on selection.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
//by default on page load
$("#price1").inputmask({
  alias: "currency",
  prefix: '₺ '
});

//apply prefix on select option change
$(document).on('change', '#exchange', function() {
  var exchangeID = +$(this).val(); //parse as number not - by default is string
  if (exchangeID == 1) {
    $("#price1").inputmask({
      alias: "currency",
      prefix: '$ '
    });
  } else if (exchangeID == 2) {
    $("#price1").inputmask({
      alias: "currency",
      prefix: '€ '
    });
  } else if (exchangeID == 3) {
    $("#price1").inputmask({
      alias: "currency",
      prefix: '£ '
    });
  } else if (exchangeID == 4) {
    $("#price1").inputmask({
      alias: "currency",
      prefix: '₺ '
    });
  }
});
```

```css
input.monerate {
  text-align: left !important;
  width: 300px;
}

select {
  width: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.2.6/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin:10px;">
  <label for="exchange">Choose a currency:</label>

  <select name="exchange" id="exchange" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    <option value="1">USD</option>
    <option value="2">Euro</option>
    <option value="3">Pound</option>
    <option value="4">TL</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div style="margin:10px;">
  <label>Price:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control text-left monerate" id="price1" name="price1" placeholder="₺ 0.00" data-inputmask="'alias': 'numeric', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoGroup': true, 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': false, 'placeholder': '0'" />
</div>
```